# Host Change - What is a good method for testing SSL before pointing DNS at new host?

Tags: https, iis7

Version 1 of a web application is on an old Host.

Version 2 is on a new host, operating on a test domain.

At launch, we will point the official domain at the new host.

However, I would like to verify that we have the SSL certificate installed correctly on the new host before pointing the domain at the new host.

I exported the certificate, but it is my understanding that the SSL certificate only works for the single domain it was issued to, so I'm not sure how to test that we have SSL setup pre-launch.

Any ideas?

Comment: It will show you a warning that certificate and domain name mismatch etc. If you pass that warning (accept certificate temporarily etc) and you will see the page content, then certificate was installed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could you set up that domain locally to point to the new IP

Not sure if it works for https but if you play with your local DNS it should work.

Comment: I'd guess this would work. As toby says, edit your hosts file to point that domain to the new server IP for your PC only. Test it works then change your main DNS over.

Answer (score 1):

Https will work, but most browsers today will show a warning that the certificate does not match the website address. The warning message shows which website the certificate is issued for.